# selenium how to locate this type of element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, linkedin-api

This element is a arrow button which is used to expand a block.
That element is a arrow button of linked-in website of messaging box.
There is a messaging box in bottom right corner of linked-in website page.
So I want to click on that arrow.I tried many paths but it gives me nosuchelement exception.
The main thing is id="ember84" this id always changes of that element whenever we refresh page
so this below path doesn't work

```
xpath("//button[@id='ember84']")
```

This is the HTML of that complete element

```
<button id="ember84" class="msg-overlay-bubble-header__control msg-overlay-bubble-header__control--new-convo-btn artdeco-button artdeco-button--circle artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view" xpath="1">  <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-down-icon" class="artdeco-button__icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M1 5l7 4.61L15 5v2.39L8 12 1 7.39z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>

<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    You are on the messaging overlay. Press enter to minimize it.
</span></button>
```

I tried this path also but it gives nosuchelement exception

```
msg = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[1]//li-icon[1]//span[constains(text(), "You are on the messaging overlay. Press enter to minimize it.")]')
```

[image]
so, how to locate that element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist lets use these imports to find elements

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Next if you look at the html around the button, it is in a div with unique text in the class, `msg-overlay-bubble-header__controls`. Inside that div are two buttons, from the sceenshot it looks like you want the second one. So you can get the minimize button with the following:

```
minimize_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class, 'msg-overlay-bubble-header__controls')]//button")))[1]
```

Comment: by this your solution it is clicking on second button (new message button ), but I want to click on third button ( minimize button)

Comment: Thanks i got solution you just need to change 1 to 2 in that last part of XPath .Please update your solution to this `minimize = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class, 'msg-overlay-bubble-header__controls')]//button")))[2]
`

Comment: 1) my first question is that how do came to know that that class-name is unique in whole HTML ? maybe other element can have same class-name, right?

Comment: 2) my second question is that what is that [1] in the last part of XPath ? i have never seen XPath where [1] are written outside the () this brackets. this is xpath right ? `//div[contains(@class, 'msg-overlay-bubble-header__controls')]//button ` or this one ? `//div[contains(@class, 'msg-overlay-bubble-header__controls')]//button[2]` Which one is correct ?can you please help me ?

Comment: for my 2) question is this correct , that whatever element we are locating by `//div[contains(@class, 'msg-overlay-bubble-header__controls')]//button` we are getting a list (array) of elements in that div thats why we are selecting the second element (index 1) that's why we are writing [1] at end ?

Comment: @PranavPatil correct `[1]` returns the second element in the list of elements found from the xpath.

Comment: For the question about how I know the class is unique, I searched the page for that text and found one result.